# Issue with goto statement along with if else condition

Tags: perl

I am trying to create a simple perl assignment for equality check and goto label concept.
User enters numbers , equality check happens, user is asked if they want to check more , if yes then it repeats, else it exits. Using "goto " for this
Issue- y/n checks for repeating,y is for repeating Label.  even if I enter "n" it keeps going to the label Loop . 
Why is the "if" condition containing "goto" not getting honored?
Code below

```
#Checking Equality

Loop: print "\Checking Equality\n";
print "Enter number for variable a\n";
$a = <stdin>;
print "Enter number for variable b\n";
$b = <stdin>;
if ( $a == $b ) {
    print 'a and b are equal';
    print "\n\n";
}
else {
    print 'a and b are not equal';
}
print "\n\n";
print "do you want to check more? Enter y/n\n";
$c = <stdin>;
if ( $c == "y" ) {
    goto Loop;
}
elsif ( $c == "n" ) {
    print "Exiting\n";
}
```

Output-

```
Checking Equality
Enter number for variable a
3
Enter number for variable b
4
a and b are not equal

do you want to check more? Enter y/n
n         
Checking Equality   #### despite of entering n goto Loop is getting executed
Enter number for variable a
```

Comment: the if should check the eq and not ==. You are using the numeric comparison and not the string comparison.

Comment: Er... why aren't you using an actual loop? `goto` occasionally has a use, but should not replace other more appropriate control flow constructs like `for` or `while`.

Comment: Re "*`goto` occasionally has a use", I use it in C regularly ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60237695/589924)), but never in Perl.

Comment: @Shawn he mentioned in the question "perl assignment for equality check and goto label concept."

Answer (score 5):

Just use [chomp](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) function to remove newline(s), and use [eq](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) comparison for string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

Loop: print "\nChecking Equality\n";
print "Enter number for variable a\n";
my $a = <stdin>;
print "Enter number for variable b\n";
my $b = <stdin>;
if ( $a == $b ) {
    print 'a and b are equal';
    print "\n\n";
}
else {
    print 'a and b are not equal';
}
print "\n\n";
print "do you want to check more? Enter y/n\n";

chomp(my $c = <stdin>);

if ( $c eq "y" ) {
    goto Loop;
}
else {
    print "Exiting\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen not best approach to use a label for `goto`.

Instead loop would be more appropriate to perform user input. User stays in the loop until he/she will not specify that he/she ready to leave.

User's input also should be stripped off newline symbol `\n` before it can be used for comparison.

As user suppose to provide input several time then it would be beneficial to use small subroutine to print 'input prompt', collect input, strip newline symbol and return input value. By doing so the program becomes shorter and easier to read.

String comparison operation performed with `eq`, number comparison performed with `==`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $answer = 'y';

while( $answer eq 'y' ) {
    my $num_1 = get_input('Enter variable num_1: ');
    my $num_2 = get_input('Enter variable num_2: ');

    my $compare = $num_1 == $num_2 ? 'EQUIAL' : 'NOT EQUIAL';

    say "\nNumbers are $compare\n";

    $answer = get_input('Would you like to continue? (y/n) ');
    $answer = lc $answer;
    say '-' x 35;
}

sub get_input {
    my $msg = shift;
    my $input;

    print $msg;
    $input = <>;
    chomp $input;

    return $input;
}
```