# What do you do if you enqueue faster than dequeue?

Tags: c, queue, pthreads, mutex

I am working with pthreads in C. I have thread 1 that receives data from a piece of hardware, and that data is placed into a queue. I have thread 2 that gets notified when data is in the queue and processes that data. Pseudo-code of my actual code is below.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* inputThread(void *ptr){
    while(){
        getData(var1); //Notified by external hardware interrupt when data is available. var1 will hold new data
        enqueue(q1, var1);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
            pthread_cond_signal(&condition1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
    }
}

void* processDataThread(void *ptr){
    short data_to_process[];
    while(){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
            while (emptyqueue(q1)) { 
                    pthread_cond_wait(&condition1,&lock1); //wait for inputthread to fill queue
                }
            data_to_process=dequeue(q1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);

        process_data(data_to_process); //causes thread to slow down
    }
}

int main(void){
    pthread_t input_thread_id;
    pthread_t thr[10];
    struct queue q1;
    struct queue q2;

    //
    //
    //some code to initiate queues, locks/mutex, conditions, etc.
    //
    //

    for (j) {
        pthread_create(&thr[j], NULL, processDataThread,(void*) &ptr);  
    }
    sleep(3); //sleep to let processthreads start up
    pthread_create(&input_thread_id, NULL, inputThread,(void*) &ptr);
}
```

I am sure that the enqueue and dequeue is working. I wrote out to a file and verified that whatever I receive in the inputThread is dequeued. I have a problem when the `process_data()` function is placed into the code. The function will slow down the processDataThread, causing the inputThread to fill the queue before processDataThread can dequeue. This results in missed data because the inputThread is working faster than the processDataThread. If I comment out the `process_data()' function, queue does not overflow. Even after increasing the number of processDataThreads (I have tried 3, 5, and 10), queue is still being enqueued faster than dequeued.

runtime `getData()` to `dequeue()` is .01s, and program continuously runs in loop without queue filling
runtime `getData()` to `process_data()` is .05s, and queue fills up after a few seconds.

What am I doing wrong? I thought increasing the number of processDataThread would resolve the issue of enqueue faster than dequeue, but it did not.

Comment: How many cores are available ? Is process_data cpu bound ?

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo but should not the enqueue function be inside the critical section?  And increasing the queue size does not help at all?

Comment: This makes no sense: `pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1); pthread_cond_signal(&condition1); pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);` ...ok, it's not as bad as I thought. Just inefficient. The call to `pthread_cond_signal` should be inside of `enqueue`, and one before releasing the lock

Comment: Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem. See [mcve]

Comment: @AnaKhorguani I was under the impression that since only one thread is ever enqueuing, it did not have to be inside critical section. Enqueue only touches tail, while dequeue touches head. Dequeue is inside critical section because more than 1 thread accesses that function.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. But in dequeue when you are checking if the queue is empty, it can be comparing head and tail with each other, that will cause data race at least, but ok maybe this does not create a problem. I just noticed as well that you don't check if the queue is full before calling enqueue, so you might be overwriting to the entries that are not consumed yet. This is not an issue?

Comment: I see that this is already mentioned in the answer. I would just say that maybe instead of abandoning the items, enqueue overwrites to the unconsumed entries because it does not check whether or not the queue is already full. Maybe adding this check will solve the problem?

Comment: You have a good point with the data race condition...I will fix that. Also, I am checking full condition within enqueue function, so I am not overwriting. Sorry, I didn't make that clear in the post. I have to have a fixed queue size in this project, but it is set at 4000 where the data I receive is only about 200-300 entries at a time.

Comment: Re "*Enqueue only touches tail, while dequeue touches head*", That's not true. The enqueue changes whether the queue is empty or not, and dequeue checks if the queue is empty or not. There is a definitely a reader and a writer accessing the same variable (whether it's `head`, `tail` or something else).

Comment: Why would enqueue check if empty? Enqueue should check if full, and if not full then add item to queue. If it checks for emptiness but the queue is actually full, it wouldn't be able to add to queue correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> *The function will slow down the processDataThread, causing the inputThread to fill the queue before processDataThread can dequeue.*

That's normal. The work done by threads is often slower than the generation of the input for those threads (which could be as simple as reading lines from a file). Keep in mind that we use threads to parallelize slow processes.

> *This results in missed data*

Something wrong with your queue if it's losing data!

> *I am sure that the enqueue and dequeue is working.*

No, a queue that loses data isn't "working".

---

You didn't show the code you are trying to debug as required, so we can only guess at the problem. It sounds like you have a fixed-size queue and that `enqueue` just abandons the item to add to the queue if the queue is full. This is a bug.

If that's the issue, either grow the queue when it gets full, or block until there's space to enqueue what you want to enqueue. [This working queue implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60237695/589924) does the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Nothing is actually wrong with queue. I have to have a fixed queue size in this project. If I grow the queue when it's full, eventually queue will be too big because the does not fix the issue of data being enqueued faster than dequeued. If I block, then I'll miss data that isn't able to be enqueued. I can't stop the external hardware sending me data just because my queue is full.

Comment: Problem was solved by changing the processData() function to run faster. Problem could have also been solved by slowing down data coming in from the external hardware, but this was not a good solution for my project. I have a single core system which is why increasing number of processing threads did not help.

Comment: Re "*Nothing is actually wrong with queue.*", You said it lost data, and then you asked how to avoid that. If that's not a problem, why did you ask how to fix it? You also showed the caller has to handle internal matters such as signaling

Comment: Re "*If I block, then I'll miss data that isn't able to be enqueued*", That makes no sense unless you're sampling real-time data, in which case you can't use a fixed-size queue without risking data loss unless you can garantee the consumer handles the data faster than the producer. (You could use a file or a db as a queue that feeds the MT queue). But your question wasn't about that.

Comment: If you are using a dynamic sized queue and the consumer never consumes data fast enough, then eventually your queue will be too big. My original question was asking if my consumer code was wrong.The queue being able to enqueue and dequeue was correct, but enqueue was happening faster than dequeue. That is what I was asking to be fixed. It ended up being a hardware problem of single-core, where I thought I had more than 1 core. That is where the confusion was coming from. After finding this out, I fixed the the consumer to run faster than data coming in and I am using one thread.

Comment: Re "*My original question was asking if my consumer code was wrong.*", No, or at least not just that.

Comment: RE "*The queue being able to enqueue and dequeue was correct*", No, I pointed out two bugs in it.

Comment: Re "*That is what I was asking to be fixed.*", No, the question did not ask for help to optimize code it didn't even show or mention.

Comment: Re "*After finding this out, I fixed the the consumer to run faster than data coming in and I am using one thread.*", I think you mean two? There's no point in using a queue if there's only one thread.