# thread pool with is not returning variable

Tags: c, queue, threadpool

I'm learning about queues and how to implement them with a thread pool (both of which are fairly new to me). I Thought I modified an example I found online correctly, but the pclient variable in my thread function is always NULL. Does anybody with more experience know what is going on?

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "myqueue2.h"

#define THREAD_POOL_SIZE 3
#define MAX_INT 10

pthread_t thread_pool[THREAD_POOL_SIZE];
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *thread_function(void *arg);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    queue q1;
    // Create a bunch of threads to handle future data
    for(int i=0; i < THREAD_POOL_SIZE; i++){
        pthread_create(&thread_pool[i], NULL, thread_function, NULL);
        printf("Thread %d created\n",i);
    }
    printf("Threads created\n");

    //Create linked list
    for(int i=0; i < MAX_INT; i++){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    int *client = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *client = i;
    enqueue(&i);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

    return 0;
}

void *thread_function(void *arg){
    while (true){
        int *pclient = dequeue();
        if (pclient != NULL){
            //We have stuff to do
            int t;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            t = dequeue();
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            printf("t = %d\n",t);
        } else {
            printf("No work to do\n");
        }
    }
}
```

myqueue2.c

```
#include "myqueue2.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

node_t *head = NULL;
node_t *tail = NULL;


void enqueue(int *value){
    node_t  *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    newnode->value = value;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    //if there is a tail, connect that tail to this new node.
    if (tail == NULL){
        head = newnode; //make sure the head still makes sense
    } else {
    tail->next = newnode;
    }
    tail = newnode;
}

int* dequeue(){
    //make sure queue is empty
    if (head == NULL){
        return NULL;
    } else{

    //save result we want to return
    int *result = head->value;

    //save head of queue
    node_t *tmp = head;

    // take it off the queue
    head = head->next;

    if (head == NULL){tail = NULL;}
    free(tmp);
    return result;
    }
}
```

myqueue2.h

```
#ifndef MYQUEUE_H_
#define MYQUEUE_H_

typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct node node_t;

typedef struct{
    node *head;
    node *tail;
} queue;

void enqueue(int *value);
int* dequeue();

#endif
```

Comment: Soooo many warnings! Don't you have warnings enabled? (I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with `gcc`)

Comment: You can't call `dequeue` without holding the lock. You do that in `thread_function` in the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You exit as soon as you finish creating the thread. You need to wait for the threads to complete. You can use `pthread_join` to wait for the threads to exit.

The next problem is that your threads never exit. Once the queue is empty and nothing else will be added to it, the threads need to exit.

Other problems:

- ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings. Sooo many errors.
- When a thread obtains something from the queue, it just discard it and uses the next thing (if any) in the queue instead.
- Mutually-exclusive access to the queue is not always ensured. (See the first call to `dequeue`.)
- Memory leaks. None of the blocks passed to `enqueue` are freed.
- You are busy waiting, sucking up all the CPU instead of waiting for something to do.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60236492/589924) (Uses a circular buffer instead of a linked list, but that's rather irrelevant.)