# Threadsafe Queue in C getting Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, multithreading, data-structures, queue

I'm new to C and even newer to multithreading and attempting to create a threadsafe queue datastructure. It's getting a seg fault error at line 116 in dequeue() (commented in the code), and I was wondering if anyone could see any obvious issues with my implementation. Thanks so much

```
typedef struct node{
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

extern int directoryThreads;
//unbounded queue for file and directory queue
typedef struct {
    node *head;;
    node *tail;
  int activeThreads;
    int open;
    int count;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    pthread_cond_t read_ready;
    //pthread_cond_t write_ready;
} queue_t;

char *dequeue(queue_t *Q)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&Q->lock); //lock queue

  if(isempty(Q)){
    Q->activeThreads--;
    if(Q->activeThreads == 0){
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&Q->lock);
        return NULL;
    }
    while (isempty(Q) && Q->activeThreads>0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&Q->read_ready, &Q->lock);
    }
    if (isempty(Q)){
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&Q->lock);
        return NULL;
    }
    Q->activeThreads++;
  }

  //printf("%s", "Dequeued: ");
  //display(Q->head);
  char *item = (char *) malloc(strlen(Q->head->data) + 1); //segault here
  item = Q->head->data;

  if(Q->count>1){
    Q->head = Q->head->next;
  }
  else{
    Q->head = NULL;
  }
  Q->count--;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&Q->lock);

    return item;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is elsewhere. (I didn't rule out a problem with the signaling protocol that leads to a race condition, but I doubt it. More on that later.)

If the signal is thrown by `Q->head->data`, `Q->head` contains garbage, or `isempty(Q)` and `Q->head != NULL` are in disagreement.

If the signal is thrown by `strlen`, `Q->head->data` contains garbage, or the string isn't properly NUL-terminated.

---

That doesn't mean there are no issues with `dequeue`.

- You allocate memory in `dequeue` for no reason.
- Worse, you overwrite the pointer returned by `malloc` on the very next line, causing a memory leak.
- `dequeue` never changes `Q->tail` even though it should be `NULL` when `Q->head` is `NULL`.
- The signaling protocol is overly complex.

Fixed:

```c
// Call done() when nothing will be added to the queue anymore.
// This is done to unblock calls to dequeue, and
// to the cause future calls to return immediately.
void Queue_done(queue_t *Q) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&Q->lock);

   Q->done = 1;

   // In case another thread is blocked in dequeue().
   pthread_cond_signal(&Q->read_ready);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&Q->lock);
}


char *Queue_dequeue(queue_t *Q) {
   pthread_mutex_lock(&Q->lock);

   while (!Q->head && !Q->done)
      pthread_cond_wait(&Q->read_ready, &Q->lock);

   char *rv;
   if (Q->head) {
      rv = Q->head->data;

      Q->head = Q->head->next;
      if (!Q->head)
         Q->tail = NULL;

      --Q->count;
   } else {
      // done() was called and queue is empty.
      rv = NULL;
   }

   // In case another thread is blocked in dequeue().
   pthread_cond_signal(&Q->read_ready);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&Q->lock);
   return rv;
}
```

Example program:

```c
static queue_t Q;

void consumer(void) {
   while (1) {
      char *job = Queue_dequeue(&Q);
      if (!job)
         break;

      // Do something with `job`.

      free(job);
   }
}

int main(void) {
   Queue_init(&Q);

   // Creates consumer threads here.

   // Add stuff to queue here.
   //   -or-
   // Create producer threads wait for them to complete here.

   Queue_done(&Q);

   // Wait for consumer threads to complete here.

   Queue_destroy(&Q);
}
```

---

I have previously [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60237695/589924) a working thread-safe queue implementation with demo. (It uses a fixed-sized circular buffer rather than a linked list, though.)