# pthread_join() for unknown number of threads

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

poll() in main() waits for some sort of a trigger from another application and when there is a trigger, pollHandler() is executed. In pollHandler(), I want to start 'n' number of threads based on the number of requests in the poll message.

But now in pollHandler(), when I want to use pthread_join in a different *for* loop, I don't have access to the thread_ids. I could create an array of pthread ids and use it outside the *for* loop block accessible to both pthread_create and pthread_join but the poll() function is active and it could get called again and again, thus overwriting the thread ids. How do I keep things clean here - wait for each thread to finish and make room to have more threads?

```
int pollHandler(){
int num_req = poll.size();
  for(int i=0; i < num_req; i++){
    // start thread for each req
    pthread_t tid;

    // thread paramters dynamically allocated and freed later
    struct parameters *p = (struct parameters*)malloc(sizeof(struct parameters));

    if((pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_func, p) != 0){
      return -1;
    }
  }

  for(int i=0; i < num_req; i++){
    // pthread_join here but no access to thread ids?
  }
 return 0; 
}

int main(){
  ......
  while(1){
    poll(); //waits for a trigger from another application
  }
}
```

Comment: So you're asking how to extend an array? `realloc`

Comment: But you need to clean up the thread or risk running out resources. So you probably need something a lot more complex. You'd probably want some kind of associative array keyed by thread id so you can remove entries from the "middle". And you'd need to be able to detect a thread ending while polling. (Or least check which threads are no longer running before creating more).

Comment: *unknown number of threads*?!?!  Who's running around inside your process and creating threads without your knowledge?

Comment: Redesign with a thread pool - create one producer/consumer queue and hang 128 'while(true){read_queue; process message} threads off it as soon as your program starts.  Don't ever create any more threads and don't try to terminate any.  No join, no thread id's, no thread micro-management, no problem.  pthread_join() is just dire and strangles many attempted multithreaded apps at birth:(

Comment: @AndrewHenle By unknown, I mean an arbitrary number.

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks for the suggestion, I will come up with a thread pool.

Comment: Thread pool good. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60237695/589924). This uses a fixed-size buffer, but you could use an adjustable-length array (using `realloc`) instead if you want (but do you really?)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to start 'n' number of threads based on the number of requests in the poll message.

This design is fundamentally flawed: if you get a request with (say) 10,000 requests, it is unlikely that you will be able to create a separate thread to handle each one, and even if you could, thread creation and destruction are inefficient and best avoided.

A much better design is to start a thread pool, and dispatch work to them, waiting for all work to be completed before returning, as Martin James suggested.

That said, here is correct (except error checking is omitted for clarity) way to implement your current design:

```
int pollHandler(){
  int num_req = poll.size();
  pthread_t *tids = calloc(num_req * sizeof(pthread_t));
  for(int i=0; i < num_req; i++){
    // start thread for each req
    // thread paramters dynamically allocated and freed later
    struct parameters *p = (struct parameters*)malloc(sizeof(struct parameters));

    if((pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, thread_func, p) != 0){
// bug here.
      return -1;
    }
  }

  for(int i=0; i < num_req; i++){
    pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
  }
  free(tids);
  return 0;
```

> I could create an array of pthread ids and use it outside the for loop block accessible to both pthread_create and pthread_join but the poll() function is active and it could get called again and again, thus overwriting the thread ids.

Unless `pollHandler()` can *interrupt* another `pollHandler()`, it *will not* be invoked until previous invocation finishes, so the code above is "safe".

If `pollHandler()` can run as part of an interrupt, then your code is already hopelessly broken (neither `malloc`, nor `pthread_create` are async-signal safe and thus can't be called in signal handler).

P.S. What's up with `//bug here`?

You can't just return there -- you need to join the threads you've already created. You would also need to `free(tids);` there as well.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, there should be an upper bound for the number of threads. Also, pollHandler() can be interrupted by another pollHandler(), so maybe I need to look at changing this part of the design first? _bug here_ because I can't access the thread_ids in the other for loop for pthread_join.

Comment: @bvj0412 "`pollHandler()` can be interrupted" -- are you sure? Interrupted by _what_ ?