# Multithreading Web Server pThread Issue

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am working on a project that simulates client requests and runs a process from a different file (this process was given to me, so I'm not supposed to edit it).

I have to use the producer-consumer method for this problem and use semaphores and a mutex lock to ensure no deadlocking, etc. I am running into the issue that my threads don't seem to realize when there is a connection and aren't triggered to complete the jobs on the server. The program creates the threads successfully, but I think I'm just missing something or not understanding the basics of how all the things I mentioned above work together. I want to understand the logic of what triggers a thread to begin working and how that makes sense with a listener / socket system waiting on a client connection. Here is a breakdown of the code, I don't want to include all of it, just the frameworks of how it all works.

```
#define MAX_REQUEST 100

int port, numThread;
typedef int bufferItem;
bufferItem buffer[MAX_REQUEST]; // shared buffer
int bufferIndex;
bool connection = false;
pthread_t threads[MAX_REQUEST];
sem_t full;
sem_t empty;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

int insertItem(bufferItem item) {
    // This method adds the item in the argument to the buffer and increments the buffer index.
    if(bufferIndex < MAX_REQUEST) {
        buffer[bufferIndex] = item;
        bufferIndex++;
        return(0); // success
    }
    else {
        return(-1); // error
    }
}

int removeItem() {
    bufferItem item;
    if(bufferIndex > 0) {
        bufferIndex--;
        item = buffer[bufferIndex];

        process(item); // run process (outside method) HERE

        return(0); // success
    }
    else {
        return(-1); // error
    }  
}

int req_handler() {
    // this method opens a socket and starts HTTP server listening on port
    // after connection to client is successful, following code executes
    while (1) {
        int s;
        s = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);
        if (s < 0) break;
        bool connection = true;
        printf("Connected!\n");

        //put in request for info (file descriptor) into shared buffer
        insertItem(s);
        sem_post(&empty); // I think I may have an error here, I have tried different things to trigger the thread but nothing works
    }
    // socket is closed
}

void *producer (void *arg) {
    // tests if there is a connection using a boolean
    // decrements buffer with empty semaphore
    // locks mutex
    int ret = insertItem(gettid()); // put item in buffer
    // unlocks mutex so other threads can use
    // increments buffer with full semaphore
}

void *consumer (void *arg) {
    // tests if there is a connection using a boolean
    // decrements full semaphore
    // locks mutex
    int ret = removeItem(); // put item in buffer
    // unlocks mutex
    // increments buffer with empty semaphore
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // sets up command line arguments to get port number and number of threads
    // initializes semaphores and mutex
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    sem_init(&empty, 0, MAX_REQUEST);
    sem_init(&full, 0, 0);

    int threadNum[numThread]; // keep track of threads

    for (i = 0; i < numThread; i++) { // create threads
        threadNum[i] = i;
        if (i == 0) {
            if(pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, producer, (void *)&threadNum[i]) != 0) {
                perror("Producer: Thread creation error");
            }
        } else {
            if(pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, consumer, (void *)&threadNum[i]) != 0) {
                perror("Consumer: Thread creation error");
            }
        }
        printf("Main: Thread Created :)\n");
    }

    // wait until all threads have exited (joined)
    for(i = 0; i < numThread; i++) {
        printf("Main: Thread Joined with numThread: %d and i %d \n",numThread,i);
        if(pthread_join(threads[i], NULL) != 0) {
            perror("Main: Thread join error");
        } 
    }

    req_handler(); // starts listener

    printf("All threads joined, destrying semaphores and mutex :)\n");

    // destroys semaphores and mutexes

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nothing ever downs/waits `empty`

Comment: Nothing ever ups/posts `full`

Comment: Nothing ever downs/waits `full`

Comment: Can you use a cond var instead of a semaphore? That's what I'd use. Or rather, that's what [I did use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60237695/589924).

Comment: @ikegami I was actually thinking about that too - the semaphores seem messy but the assignment requested mutex and the full/empty ones. I might try with the conditional cuz that makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your semaphores are going unused. This isn't a coding issue, but an understanding issue, and I'll answer it as such.

I'll be explaining it as if storage can contain more than one (*n*) item, but this works even if storage can only accommodate one item. Similarly, I'll be explaining it as there are multiple producers (*p*) and multiple consumers (*c*), but this works even if there are only one of each. However, if n=1, p=1 and c=1, there's no need for the mutex.

---

The flow of data is:

Producers -> Storage -> Consumers

In order to achieve this,

- A consumer needs to wait for data to become available in storage.
- A producer needs to wait for space to become available in storage.

This can be achieved using two semaphores:

- One that keeps track of the number of items in storage.
- One that keeps track of the amount of free space in storage.

Logic:

- Initially:

  - There are 0 items in storage.
  - There are *n* spaces for items.
- When a producer wants to add an item:

  - They must wait for space to become available.
- After a producer produces an item:

  - They must signal this by increasing the number of items in storage.
- When a consumer wants to consume an item:

  - They must wait for an item to become available.
- After a consumer consumes an item:

  - They must signal this by increasing the amount of space in storage.

These correspond to the init, down/wait and up/post operations of the two semaphores.

A mutex is used when actually reading/modifying the storage (once the semaphore has indicated it's in the desired state).

Comment: Thank you so much, this actually makes a lot of sense now in terms of what the semaphores and mutex are used for.

Comment: So my order is
--producer--

sem_wait(&empty) ||

mutex lock ||

insertItem ||

mutex unlock ||

sem_post(&full) ||

--consumer--

sem_wait(&full) ||

mutex lock ||

removeItem ||

mutex unlock ||

sem_post(&empty) ||


I think what is confusing me a little is that because I didnt write the process method, that takes an int as a parameter, I don't quite understand what the "data" is that I am storing. I do need the mutex because there are multiple consumers (just one producer since it is always waiting on the consumer anyway)

Comment: yup, all of that is 100% correct.