# Periodically trigger pthread workers and wait for completion

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I would like to create a set of N pthreads under control of the original process.  I'd like to control them as in this pseudocode:

```
create_n_threads();

While(1) {
    main task modifies a global variable "phase" to control the type of work
    trigger the N threads to wake up and do work based on the global "phase" variable
    wait until all threads have completed their tasks
    main task does meta-calculation on the partial results of all the workers
}
```

I've tried pthread_barrier_wait().  It works well to trigger a compute cycle, but it doesn't give me a way to know when every task has completed.  How do I know when all the threads are done so that I can safely do my meta-calculation on the result?  I don't want to use pthread_join, because these work cycles will be in a tight loop and I don't want the overhead of killing and recreating the tasks on each cycle.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <unistd.h>     // for sleep()

#define NTHREADS 4
pthread_barrier_t b;

typedef struct threadargs {
int id;             // thread ID 0-\>N
int phase;          // either 0 or non zero to set blk/red phase
} THREADARGS;

int phase=0;
int cycle=0;

// worker function
// gets called with a pointer to THREADARGS structure
// which tells worker their id, starting, ending column to relax, and the red/black phase

void *thread_func(void *x)
{
int tid;                    // thread id

    int *retval = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));   // so it persists across thread death
    tid = ((THREADARGS *) x)->id;
    
    while(1) {                  // wait to be triggered
        printf("%d: %d %d\n", cycle, tid, phase);
        pthread_barrier_wait(&b);
    }
    
    *retval = 2*tid;
    pthread_exit((void *)retval);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
pthread_t threadids[NTHREADS];      // store os thread ids
THREADARGS thread_args[NTHREADS];           // arguments to thread
int rc, i;

    // initialize the multiprocess barrier 
    pthread_barrier_init(&b, NULL, NTHREADS+1);
    
    /* spawn the threads */
    for (i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i) {
        thread_args[i].id = i;
        printf("spawning thread %d\n", i);
        if((rc=pthread_create(&threadids[i], NULL, thread_func, (void *) &thread_args[i]))!=0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot create thread %d\n",i);
            exit(8);
        };
    }
    
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {              // do ten iterations
        printf("cycle %d\n", i);
        phase=(phase+1)%3;
        cycle++;
        pthread_barrier_wait(&b);       // trigger all the workers and wait for all to complete
    }
    
    exit(2);    // just kill everything

}
```

This example produces output like:

```
!) pthread
spawning thread 0
spawning thread 1
spawning thread 2
spawning thread 3
0: 0 0
0: 1 0
cycle 0
1: 2 1
1: 3 1
1: 3 1
1: 1 1
1: 2 1
1: 0 1
cycle 1
cycle 2
3: 1 0
3: 3 0
3: 2 0
3: 0 0
3: 0 0
3: 2 0
3: 3 0
cycle 3
3: 1 0
4: 1 1
4: 2 1
4: 0 1
4: 3 1
```

You can see that some workers are running multiple times per cycle and that the "phase" variable doesn't count properly from cycle to cycle.  What I want is something like:

```
cycle 1
1: 0 0
1: 1 0
1: 2 0
1: 3 0
cycle 2
2: 0 1
2: 1 1
2: 2 1
2: 2 1
cycle 3
3: 0 2
...
```

Of course the print statements from each task will be scrambled but I want to trigger all 4 pthreads to perform a task "0,1,2" and for them all to finish so that I can work with their results and safely change global variables for the next cycle.

Comment: Your code is full of escape characters, which is invalid C syntax.

Comment: Sorry,  I just cut and pasted my example.  I don't know the proper idiom for adding code to stack overflow.  I didn't see any mechanism to browse my filesystem for a code file.

Comment: Where did you get that example holding all these escape sequences? If you just copy&paste your own code into the browser window it should work fine.

Comment: I edited the original code to remove the escape sequences.  It was posted by cutting and pasting from a linux xterm into a windows virtual machine firefox browser.  My apologies for not noticing the added characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [pthread_barrier_wait](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html)

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The calling thread shall block until the required number of threads have called `pthread_barrier_wait()` specifying the barrier.
>
> When the required number of threads have called `pthread_barrier_wait()` specifying the barrier, the constant `PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD` shall be returned to **one unspecified thread** and zero shall be returned to **each of the remaining threads**.
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> Upon successful completion, the `pthread_barrier_wait()` function shall return `PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD` for a **single** (arbitrary) thread synchronized at the barrier and zero for **each of the other** threads. Otherwise, an error number shall be returned to indicate the error.

Therefore:

```
int res = pthread_barrier_wait(barrier);
if (res == PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD) {
    //only one single (arbitrary) thread will reach this point
    //and only if all other threads have reached the barrier
} else {
   //all others will see this part
}
```

---

With two barriers, you can do the following:

```
int done = 0;

void* thread_func(void *arg) {

    while (!done) {

        //wait until all threads have signal to go
        pthread_barrier_wait(start_barrier);

        //all green, lets do the work ...
        //as last operation, store the result in a dedicated global variable
        //as long as only this thread will access it, no need to
        //protect it with a mutex

        //after work is done, wait until all the others are done too
        pthread_barrier_wait(stop_barrier);

    }

}

int main()
{
    //all the init stuff (inclusive thread creation)

    do {
        
        //do preparations before the threads starts doing their work
        //set global vars etc.
        //e.g. done = 1;

        //all threads are waiting for the last thread to get going
        //give green signal
        pthread_barrier_wait(start_barrier);

        //while the threads doing their job
        pthread_barrier_wait(stop_barrier);

        //at this point, each task has done its job
        //and it is guaranteed, that all data will no longer
        //accessed by any thread, therefore no protection needed

        //do the main calculation

    } while (!done);

}
```

Comment: The double barrier approach is the simplest solution.  I hadn't considered using two different barrier variables and was worried about using the same one twice and somehow getting out of sync.  Using to different variables seems to be foolproof and my code is working correctly now. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that once the threads passed the barrier they want to continue doing their work, but they can't continue until one has done the main calculation (and prrepared the data for the next iteration). No way to do that with a single barrier. Sure, using a mutex and condition variable can solve that problem, but isn't it that, what the barrier wait operation does?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cond var.

```c
int done = 0;
int work = 0;
int working = 0;
int waiting = n;
```

Worker:

```c
pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );

while ( 1 ) {
   // Wait for work to arrive.
   while ( !work && !done )
      pthread_cond_wait( &cond, &mutex );

   if ( !work && done )
      break;

   --work
   --waiting;
   ++working;
   pthread_cond_signal( &cond );

   pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );

   // Do work.

   pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );

   --working;
   ++waiting;
   pthread_cond_signal( &cond );
}

pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
```

Main:

```c
pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );

while ( 1 ) {
   work = n;
   pthread_cond_signal( &cond );

   // Wait for the workers to complete the work.
   while ( work || working )
      pthread_cond_wait( &cond, &mutex );

   // Process result.
}

done = 1;
pthread_cond_broadcast( &cond );

pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );

// Join worker threads here.
```

Note that any amount of work can be added. Less than `n` work is fine. Even more than `n` will work.

---

See also: [Thread-safe queue that supports multiple producers and consumers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60237695/589924)

Comment: Your code really helped me to understand cond variables.  Once I realize that both threads have to lock the variable and it gets unlocked when pthread_cond_wait() is called it started to make sense.  This approach is very powerful and I may use it in the future.  For my present problem, doing a double barrier wait is sufficient and easier to understand.  Thanks for your help!